# Jamaa SMPP cannot send Arabic text

Tags: c#, smpp

I am using JamaaTech SMPP library to send sms from my SMSC provider to mobile. I want to send Arabic text message however I receive Chinese letters in my mobile. Below is my code.

```
SmppClient client = new SmppClient();
SmppConnectionProperties properties = client.Properties;
properties.SystemID = "XXX";
properties.Password = "XXX";
properties.Port = XXXX;
properties.Host = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX";
properties.SourceAddress = "XXXXXXXXXX";
properties.DefaultEncoding = DataCoding.UCS2;
//Resume a lost connection after 30 seconds
client.AutoReconnectDelay = 3000;
//Send Enquire Link PDU every 15 seconds
client.KeepAliveInterval = 15000;
//Start smpp client
client.Start();
while (client.ConnectionState != SmppConnectionState.Connected)
    Thread.Sleep(100);
var msg = new TextMessage();
msg.DestinationAddress = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
msg.SourceAddress = "XXXXXXXXXX";
msg.Text = "س";
msg.RegisterDeliveryNotification = true;
client.SendMessage(msg);
```

I am really tired with trying different solutions and searching on Google. I would really appreciate if somebody could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The Chinese message should be encoded by unicode.

Comment: It wasn’t about Chinese letters, my Arabic text message was getting converted to Chinese letters which i didn’t want. Anyway, I have solved the problem.